# Nodemailer Custom SMTP not working on Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I have an error. I am using nodemailer to send emails from my Firebase application.

This what my code looks like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

admin.initializeApp();

//THESE SETTINGS WORK ON LOCAL AND LIVE. BUT I DONT WANT TO USE THEM
// const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
//     service: 'gmail',
//     auth: {
//         user: 'GMAIL HERE',
//         pass:  'GMAIL PW HERE'
//     },
// })

//THESE SETTINGS WORK ON LOCAL, BUT NOT ON LIVE.
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.mycompanyname.com",
    port: 25,
    secureConnection: false, // TLS requires secureConnection to be false
    logger: true,
    debug: true,
    secure: false,
    requireTLS: true,
    auth: {
        user: "USERNAME HERE",
        pass: "PASSWORD HERE"
    },
    tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
})

exports.sendConfirmationEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    var email_adress        = data.data.email;

    var email = {
        from: 'E-Mail Adress Goes Here',
        to: email_adress,
        subject: 'BlaBlaBla',
        text: 'BlaBlaBla',
        html: 'BlaBlaBla'
    };
    // Function to send e-mail to the user
    transporter.sendMail(email, function(err, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return { success: false };
        } else {
            return { success: true }
        }
    });

})
```

Now. If I use the GMail settings. All works fine. It sends E-Mails. However, my company has an own SMTP Server. The SMTP works for the Firebase Authentication E-Mails. It is successfully sending those emails.

The SMTP server also works when I paste the above configuration in my local environment. However, when I run this in the Firebase Cloud function it gives me the following error:

```
10:24:43.479 AM
sendConfirmationEmail
[2020-09-25 08:24:43] DEBUG [Cq6p67HnXLA] Closing connection to the server using "destroy"
10:24:43.479 AM
sendConfirmationEmail
[2020-09-25 08:24:43] ERROR Send Error: Connection timeout
10:24:44.673 AM
sendConfirmationEmail
{ Error: Connection timeout
10:24:44.673 AM
sendConfirmationEmail
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19) 
10:24:44.674 AM
sendConfirmationEmail
    at SMTPConnection._onError (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:770:20) 
10:24:44.674 AM
sendConfirmationEmail
at Timeout._connectionTimeout.setTimeout (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:235:22)
```

I've tried to play around with the different nodemailer options, but so far not a lot of success. It also makes it hard that on local it works, but when I deploy it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've faced exactly the same problem and it took some digging, but the solution is quite simple.

### Solution

---

You **cannot use** use outbound connections on **port 25** in your Cloud Function.

---

So I've changed port to 465 and used secure connection and it does work.

I have (randomly) found a mention of this at [Tips & Tricks](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) documentation page.

PS: The same limitation applies to Compute Engine (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail)).

Answer (score 2):

You should use Promises in order to manage the lifecycle of your Cloud Function, which executes an asynchronous operation which returns a promise (i.e. the `sendMail()` method). See this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details.

So, by using, as follows, the promise returned by the `sendMail()` method, instead of the callback, it should work.

```
exports.sendConfirmationEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    var email_adress = data.data.email;

    var email = {
        from: 'E-Mail Adress Goes Here',
        to: email_adress,
        subject: 'BlaBlaBla',
        text: 'BlaBlaBla',
        html: 'BlaBlaBla'
    };

    return transporter.sendMail(email).then(() => {  // Note the return here
        return { success: false };
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        // !! Here, return an instance of functions.https.HttpsError.
        // See the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
    });

});
```

---

**Note:** If you are **NOT** using Node.js 10 or 12 but Node.js 8 (which I guess is **NOT** the case, since deployment of Node.js 8 functions is no longer allowed since February 15, 2020.), read below:

If you are using Node.js version 8 in your Cloud Function, be aware that you need to be on the "Blaze" pricing plan. As a matter of fact, the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services". See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (hover your mouse on the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title)

Since your SMTP server is not a Google-owned service, you need to switch to the "Blaze" plan.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate reply! Unfortunately, this does not work for me. I am already on the Blaze plan. I'm als not sure this was the problem, because it is working with the gmail transporter object.

Answer (score 2):

1. Blaze is required
2. Port `25` won't work
3. `Node.js 12` does work
4. `tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false }` is essential to make it working

Working (`TypeScript`) code below, the use case is a contact form.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import * as Mail from 'nodemailer/lib/mailer';
import { DocumentSnapshot } from 'firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore';
import { EventContext } from 'firebase-functions';

async function onCreateSendEmail(
  snap: DocumentSnapshot,
  _context: EventContext
) {
  try {
    const contactFormData = snap.data();
    console.log('Submitted contact form: ', contactFormData);
    console.log('context: ', _context);

    // The non-null assertion signs (!) might be not required, if your IDE/TypeScript settings aren't strict.
    const mailTransport: Mail = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'mail.yourdomain.com', // Or however your SMTP provides defines it.
      port: 587, // Most probably that's your port number.
      auth: {
        user: 'yourmail@domain.com', // It could happen that your SMTP provides in user authentication requires full name of mail account. For example 'yourmail' would be not correct, 'yourmail@domain.com' would.
        pass: 'YOUR_MAIL_PASSWORD',
      },
      tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false, //! ESSENTIAL! Fixes ERROR "Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames".
      },
    });

    const mailOptions = {
      from: `${contactFormData!.formControlName} <${
        contactFormData!.formControlEmail
      }>`,
      to: 'yourmail@domain.com',
      subject: `Contact Form`,
      html: `
        <p>Message from a contact form has been send.</p>
        <h3>Message content:</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Name: ${contactFormData!.formControlName}</li>
          <li>E-mail: ${contactFormData!.formControlEmail}</li>
          ...
        </ul>
      `,
    };

    await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

exports.contactFormFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('mails/{formControlEmail}'
  )
  .onCreate(onCreateSendEmail);
```

Comment: Google Cloud also blocks 587 port

Comment: Rechecked it, and that's not true.